# Finding events using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am firing the following graph API: [https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=&type=event] to get events data in a region.
However, in this API, I want to search an event by location as well as a category (say, marathons). Basically, I want to search on 2 parameters with this API - location and category. How to do this?

Cheers,

Comment: The `q` parameter only searches in the name of the event. What you want is simply not possible directly.

Comment: Append your location to the end of your query as the q searches more than beyond the name of the event. example https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/search?q=marathon%20dublin
returns this event, despite "Dublin" not being in the name.
{
name: "Vhi Women's Mini Marathon 2018",
id: "1803645183261605",
description: "The Vhi Women's Mini Marathon is returning to a Sunday for 2018!! This year, on 3rd June 2018, we want you to join us by walking, jogging or running 10k in Dublin....",
place: {
name: "Fitzwilliam Place, Dublin, County Dublin, Ireland"
}
}

Comment: Issue is I want to search FB Graph API by location and category. In the above example, did it search for 'marathon' because it's in the title field? What is the category of the above result?